# Find the probability of selecting exactly two of the correct $ 6$ integers in a lottery

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, lotteries

I saw a question in my textbook , i have a solution for it but i am not sure.Can you corroborate my solution?

Question: Find the probability of selecting exactly two of the correct $ 6$ integers in a lottery, where the order in which these integers are selected  $matter$ ,from the positive integers not exceeding $40$

NOTE: What i meant that the order is important is that assume the the winner ticket is $ 1-13-2-31-7-24 $ but your ticket is $ 1-13-2-31-24-7$ .Then you cannot take the prize because the order is important. Namely, finding the correct numbers is not sufficient , you  must also find the correct order.

In this question, i am looking for the probability of the ticket which have exactly two correct number with correct place and four wrong numbers .

My solution: $ \frac{C(6,2).C(34,4)}{P(40,6)}$

I am not sure about solution.I dont know whether i should order the six number or not.What i meant is $ \frac{C(6,2).C(34,4).P(6,6)}{P(40,6)}$

Which one is correct? If none of them are correct , can you give me hints or full solution?

Comment: The rules are not clear.  Are you requiring that we guess two of the correct integers $\textit{ in the right places}$?  So if the winners are $\{1,10,11, 27, 31, 39\}$ then you are asking about guesses like $\{3,10,11,12,13,14\}$ but not guesses likes $\{10,11,12,13,14,15\}$?  Otherwise, what do you mean by referencing the order?

Comment: @lulu assume that the winning lottery is $1-4-5-3-17-56$ but your ticket has the order $1-4-5-3-56-17$. Then you cannot win it. The number in ticket is important for winning

Comment: @lulu as you said two of correct integers in the right places

Comment: Seems a bit messy to account for the cases in which you guess other values correctly but you put them in the wrong slots.  You can approximate the result by assuming that each guess is an independent $\frac 1{40}$ shot, and then using the binomial distribution.

Comment: @lulu thank you for your efforts and helps

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, then the order of the last four numbers chosen (but not all six) should matter. After you choose which two of the six numbers will be correct in $C(6,2)$ ways, $C(34,4)$ would only choose the remaining four numbers, but you still have to count the number of ways of arranging those four numbers; thus the $C(34,4)$ should be replaced by $P(34,4)$. Then the probability would be

$$ \
\vphantom{} \\
\frac{C(6,2) \cdot P(34,4)}{P(40,6)} \\
\vphantom{} \\
$$

However, I'm not convinced the question requires the other four numbers to be **wrong**; couldn't some or all of the four remaining numbers be among the winning numbers but just in the wrong position? In that case the probability would be more difficult. One would have to break it down into cases to ensure the other winning numbers didn't end up in their correct spots.

As an example, suppose that other than the two correct numbers, two other winning numbers were chosen but placed in the wrong positions, and the final two numbers were not among the winning numbers. The number of ways to do that would be $C(4,2) \cdot D(4,2) \cdot P(34,2)$. Here I'm using the notation $D(n,m)$ to indicate the number of ways of placing $m$ numbers in the **incorrect** positions among $n$ possible positions. I know of no formula for this except for when $m=n$, in which case it's the number of [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement). In this problem the numbers are fairly small so not too difficult to calculate manually; I'm getting $D(4,2) = 7$.

So in that case, the probability would be

$$ \
\vphantom{} \\
{\small \frac{C(6,2) \big[ \, P(34,4) + C(4,1) \, D(4,1) \, P(34,3) + C(4,2) \, D(4,2) \, P(34,2) + C(4,3) \, D(4,3) \, P(34,1) + D(4,4) \, \big]} {P(40,6)}} \\
\vphantom{} \\
$$

which (if I counted the D's correctly) would become

$$ \
\vphantom{} \\
{ \frac{C(6,2) \, \Big[ \, P(34,4) + 3 \, C(4,1) \, P(34,3) + 7 \, C(4,2) \, P(34,2) + 11 \, C(4,3) \, P(34,1) + 9 \, \Big]} {P(40,6)}} \\
\vphantom{} \\
$$